# Como esconder título das abas do JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

Preciso esconder os títulos do `JTabbedPane` pois estou criando meus próprios botões para acessar as abas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando CardLayout, ele é feito para isso

[Como usar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 3):

**Skywalker**

Não sei se existe algo do tipo `setTabVisible(boolean b)`. Mas você pode utilizar o método do `JTabbedPane` `setTabComponentAt`:

```
jTabbedPane1.setTabComponentAt(int index, Component c);
```

Você deve fazer para toda aba. Mandar `null` como componente não funcionará, mas tente mandar um painel com zero de largura e altura.